# How can I support an HTTP Proxy using Spring 5 WebClient?

Tags: spring-webflux

I am using Spring 5 WebClient.  I want to know if it is possible to configure it to use an HTTP Proxy, or if there is a way of changing it's default configuration to do so.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is something that the underlying client library should support.

When using Reactor Netty, you can do something like:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
            .tcpConfiguration(tcpClient ->
                    tcpClient.proxy(proxy -> proxy.type(ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP).host("myproxyhost")));
ReactorClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
WebClient client = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(connector).build();
```

Comment: Any examples of how to do this with a WebTestClient?

Comment: I guess WebTestClient is meant to test your app in a mock/integration setup and not an external service deployed behind a proxy.

Comment: Yeah... i was being lazy.  Here's an example... 

ReactorClientHttpConnector connector = 
 new ReactorClientHttpConnector(options -> options.httpProxy(addressSpec -> {
  return addressSpec.host(proxyHost).port(proxyPort);
 }));
  
WebTestClient client = WebTestClient
 .bindToServer(connector).baseUrl(hostname)
 .build();

Comment: Thank you for your answer. before I tried to set the JVM flags (-DproxySet = true -DproxyHost = 127.0.0.1 -DproxyPort = 9999) before runing my application but it did not work. Do you have any idea why it doesn't works in this way with the WebClient?

Comment: One addition: after ```host("myproxyhost")```  if you have port number don`t forget to put it. Otherwise it does not work. ```host("myproxyhost").port(portnumber)```.

Comment: @BrianClozel,
Good Day!
I am new to reactive programming. Can you please share an example project Github link where the proxy is used with WebClient?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

" tcpConfiguration"  is deprecated.
So used this part of code instead.

```
  HttpClient httpClient =
            HttpClient.create()
                    .proxy(proxy -> proxy.type(ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP)
                            .host(sasConfig.getProxyHost())
                            .port(Integer.parseInt(sasConfig.getProxyPort())));

    ReactorClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);

    WebClient webClient =  WebClient.builder().clientConnector(connector).build();
```

Comment: I have used the same but it throws an exception 
```failure when writing TLS control frames; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: failure when writing TLS control frames```

How do I solve this?

Comment: This worked for me. :thumbs_up:

Answer (score 1):

Sharing recent experience here

Step 1 : Define proxy environment variables

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxyHost>
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttps.proxyHost=<proxyHost>
-Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttps.nonProxyHosts=localhost
```

2. Configuration of proxy on webClient

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class WebClientConfiguration {    
    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient() {
        return WebClient.builder() //
                .defaultHeader(ACCEPT, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) //
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient())) //
                .build();
    }

    private HttpClient httpClient() {
        return HttpClient //
                .create() //
                .proxyWithSystemProperties();
    }
   ```

   }
3. Set the spring cloud proxy properties (In the application start)

   ```
   static {
      String nonProxyHosts = System.getProperty("http.nonProxyHosts");
      if (nonProxyHosts != null) {
        String regexProxyList = nonProxyHosts.replaceAll("\\.", "\\\\.").replaceAll("\\/", "\\\\/").replaceAll("\\*", ".\\*");
        System.setProperty("spring.cloud.gateway.httpclient.proxy.non-proxy-hosts-pattern", regexProxyList);
    }
    String proxyHost = System.getProperty("https.proxyHost");
    String proxyPort = System.getProperty("https.proxyPort");
    if (proxyHost != null && proxyPort != null) {
        System.setProperty("spring.cloud.gateway.httpclient.proxy.host", proxyHost);
        System.setProperty("spring.cloud.gateway.httpclient.proxy.port", proxyPort);
    }
   }
   ```